# open screen session on many remote hosts executing complex command, don't exit afterward

Tags: unix, ssh, sh, gnu-screen, gnu-parallel

I have a long list of remote hosts and I want to run a shell command on all of them.  The command takes a very long time, so I want to run the command inside `screen` *on the remote machine*, disconnecting immediately from each, and I want the terminal output on the remote to be preserved after the command exits.  There is a "tag" that should be supplied to each command as an argument.  I tried to do this with `parallel`, something like this:

```
$ cat servers.txt
user1@server1.example.com/tag1
user2@server2.example.com/tag2
# ...

$ cat run.sh
grep -v '^#' servers.txt |
    parallel ssh -tt '{//}' \
        'tag={/}; exec screen slow_command --option1 --option2 $tag other args'
```

This doesn't work: all of the remote processes are launched, but they are not detached (so the ssh sessions remain live and I don't get my local shell back), and once each command finishes, its screen exits immediately and the output is lost.

How do I fix this script?  Note: if this is easier to do with `tmux` and/or some other marshalling program besides `parallel`, I'm happy to hear answers that explain how to do it that way.

Comment: You'd probably be better off with `nohup` instead of `screen` here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
grep -v '^#' servers.txt |
  parallel -q --colsep / ssh {1} "screen -d -m bash -c 'echo do stuff \"{2}\";sleep 1000000'"
```

The final `sleep` makes sure the screen does not die. You will have 1000000 seconds to attach to it and kill it.

There is an awful lot of quoting there - especially if `do stuff` is complex.

It may be easier to make a function that computes `tag` on the remote machine. You need GNU Parallel 20200522 for this:

```
env_parallel --session

f() {
  sshlogin="$1"
  # TODO given $sshlogin compute $tag (e.g. a table lookup)
  do_stuff() {
     echo "do stuff $tag"
     sleep 1000000
  }
  export -f do_stuff
  screen -d -m bash -c do_stuff "$@"
}

env_parallel  --nonall --slf servers_without_tag f '$PARALLEL_SSHLOGIN' 

env_parallel --endsession
```